# remove commits from contributor

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I have a Git repo with a lot of old commits from a contributor. Those commits do in no way influence the current version of the repo. I would like to remove all the commits from that contributor. How to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this repo used by multiple developers? If so, any solution will require actions to be done by every developer on the project, since everyone has a copy of the repo.

Comment: No, it's a repo only used by me.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Even if the commits don't influence the current version, the use of version control is meant to show the history of the repository as well (which includes commits by the other contributor)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is with an interactive rebase. Let's say the first commit you want to delete is `abc`. Do the following: `git rebase -i abc^`. This will pop up an editor with a list of commits. Delete the lines that contain the commits you want to delete, then save/close the file. Git will then rewrite all of the commits in order, leaving out the ones you deleted.

Note that when you push to the server, you will need to use the --force option to overwrite what is there as well.